# Django 1.10 custom User 'is_superuser' clashes with the field 'is_superuser' from model

Tags: django, django-models

I write a custom user class - `CustomUser` in `models.py`, mainly followed [here](https://github.com/jonathanchu/django-custom-user-example/blob/master/customuser/accounts/models.py)

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core import validators
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin,
                                        UserManager)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    custom user, reference below example
    https://github.com/jonathanchu/django-custom-user-example/blob/master/customuser/accounts/models.py
    """
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
                                help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                                            '@/./+/-/_ characters'),
                                validators=[validators.RegexValidator(
                                    re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
    ])
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()  # if we can retrieval it from outside

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Then I registered it in `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser

# Register your models here.


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

But when I run `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create a superuser, I got the following error:

```
ERRORS:
myapp.CustomUser.is_superuser: (models.E006) The field 'is_superuser' clash
es with the field 'is_superuser' from model 'myapp.customuser'.
```

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Same error when I run `makemigrations`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `is_superuser` field is defined on `PermissionMixin`. However, `AbstractUser` also subclasses `PermissionMixin`, so you're effectively inheriting from the same class twice. This causes the field clash, as older versions of Django don't allow subclasses to override fields (recent versions allow to override fields that are defined on abstract base classes).

You either have to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionMixin`, or from just `AbstractUser`. `AbstractUser` defines some additional fields, including `username`, `is_staff` and `is_active`, and some other things.

Comment: It's my fault, I didn't realize the difference between `AbstractBaseUser` and `AbstractUser`, thanks a lot!