# Permissions from 2 django projects are merged. How to separate them?

Tags: django, django-models

Good day to all)
I created a custom user model with custom permissions. I have several projects and their permissions merged into one table('auth_permission'). Is it possible to somehow customize the table itself for these permissions to separate projects?(like `db_table = '"schema"."table"'` to the models.).Google did not give answers.

```
class TestUser(AbstractUser):
phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
email = CharField(unique=True, max_length=35, null=False, blank=False)

class Meta:
    db_table = '"fyzzys"."users"'
    permissions = [
        ("can_see_payments", "payments"),
        ("can_see_analytics", "analytics"),
    ]
```

UPD: Here is a screenshot that shows the permissions of two completely different projects at the same time from admin panel.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the django permissions or running your own custom permissions models?

Comment: @MattSeymour I am using the django permissions. If i will use custom permissions model I can choose table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to give a user permissions, you will want to add the PermissionsMixin to the User model like so.

```py
class TestUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

If you are using the `AbstractUser` you are actually already inheriting the `PermissionsMixin`.

The permissionmixin is a model within `django.contrib.auth.models`. It adds to the user model the following fields (columns in the user table); is_superuser, groups, user_permissions. The permissions mixin allows you to add (and remove) 0..*(many) individual or group permissions [to a user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

To add permissions to a user you can then use.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

# The permission needs to exist first.
permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can view poll')
u.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

The code for for the [django.contrib.auth.models.permissionsmixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L227) can be found following the link.

Comment: I got this error: (models.E006) The field 'is_superuser' clashes with the field 'is_superuser' from model 'registration1.testuser'. This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093946/django-1-10-custom-user-is-superuser-clashes-with-the-field-is-superuser-fro says, that AbstractUser and PermissionsMixin cause conflict

Comment: Sorry my bad, the abstract user brings in Permissions mixin. I will update my answer to fix. use AbstractBaseUser instead of AbstractUser

Comment: Is it possible to do without using AbstractBaseUser? I heard that it is only necessary as a last resort to use it. It will also complicate the code and will have to be rewritten for it, as a beginner I would not want this.

Comment: Another question is how to make the admin panel see the table with my permissions, and not the default

Comment: Do you mean how to get the admin panel see the TestUser models?

Comment: Now I have 2 different projects with different environments. Their permissions are in the same default table. And from the admin panel of one project, I see the permissions of the second. How to separate them?